# How to restrict json files that are stored under wwwroot folder to view from Web Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a "**client-styles.css**" in my **wwwroot / client_folder** folder. When I run my project in localhost and give that css file path in the browser its showing the entire css file in the web browser.
( localhost:5000/client_folder/client-styles.css ).

In the same way I have a folder also contains **json files** which contains sensitive information and those are also showing if we give the path to those Json files ( localhost:5000/client_folder/client-secrets.json ) in the browser. Is there any way restricting some files to view from web browser.

Thanks

Comment: Well yeah, the browser has to see css files to process it.  As for your secrets in json files, why do those have to exist on the client side?  Typically I store those in environment variables.

Comment: That's not possible. Why are you storing secets.json on wwwroot folder?

Comment: And the user secrets file is meant to be stored on your local development machine ONLY.

Comment: Hi  @GregD thanks for your answer and the reason why I'm storing in wwwroot is I'm planning to store all client related files ( custom css for particular client, js and other data like json) in a single folder. css and js files any way we have to store in wwwroot that is why I placed json file in the same folder. So can you suggest a way so that I can store all the files (css,json etc) in a single folder so that I can secure those secret files also.
 Thanks

Comment: @DeepakMishra I hope I answered your question also Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your last comment above:

It's perfectly acceptable to store css and javascript files in wwwroot.  However, do not store anything secret there.  Storing secrets like connectionstrings are best in EnvironmentVariables.